# IPython.display.Audioによる音の強さの制御について

Tags: python3

Pythonを用いて、音楽作成をしようと試みています。

音の波形の最大振幅は音の強さであると認識していますが、下のコードは最大振幅値を変えても、音が変わっていないと感じるのですが、これは変わっているのでしょうか？それかコードまたは理解がおかしいのでしょうか？

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import IPython.display

#a:最大振幅 #周波数 
def sound(a,f,sr):
    return a*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t)

#ド
f = 523.251
sr = 44100

t = np.arange(0,1,1/sr)
y = A*np.sin(2*np.pi*f[0]*t) #+ A*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t)

IPython.display.Audio(sound(a,f[1],sr),rate = sr)
#aを0.1 や　１に変えても音の大きさが変わらない
```

これは今、音の大きさを 0<a<1の範囲にしているため聞き取りにくいということなのでしょうか？
ご指導のほどよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 音量が自動で正規化されているためです。`normalize=False` 指定すると正規化が解除されます。`IPython.display.Audio(..., normalize=False)`

Comment: 本当にありがとうございました！！すみません、これはどのようにベストアンサーにできますか？

Comment: ご自身で答えを書いて承認すればよろしいかと。